# Camera2 - "Must be called from main thread of fragment host" when changing fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception

I'm trying to change the fragment after an image is taken with the following code [Google Sample - Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java).

I've implemented a callback to my MainActivity at line 839 of the above sample. However when I am trying to traverse to a different activity from that callback I receive the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of
>   fragment host

Does anyone know anyway around this?

Comment: Can you post your callback code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the working code in Kotlin
You must replace this callback with:

```
  val captureCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession,
                                            request: CaptureRequest,
                                            result: TotalCaptureResult) {
                sendBackResult(mFile)
            }
        }

        mCaptureSession!!.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureCallback, mBackgroundHandler)
    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

sendBackResult method is as follows:

```
private fun sendBackResult(resultFile: File?) {
    val fileUri = Uri.fromFile(resultFile)
    val dataIntent = Intent()
    dataIntent.data = fileUri
    dataIntent.putExtra("isFront", isFrontCamera)
    activity!!.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent)
    activity!!.finish()
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the help, ended up changing camera to use a Activity and then use the result to pass the image back.